# Add an Object in a Object in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, object

i'm trying to add an object in my object vars.

Basically, i have two variables, the first named key with "`time`", and the second "`val`" with an hours.
And i'm trying to put this two variable in my object `this.state.vars`.
In the end, i want to have something like this

```
"vars":{"time":"23:11"}
```

I already tried to do something like `this.setState({vars: {keys: val}})`

but it's not working. Do i need to do a specific call to add a new key and a new value in a Object ? Thanks

Comment: Wait, is this about setting an object key based on a variable? In that case you need square brackets: `this.setState({ vars: { ...vars, [keyVariable]: newValue }})`

Comment: @ChrisG My problem is : It's not every time "time", it can be a lot of things

Comment: Yes, I got that and edit my comment.

Comment: it's weird because when i'm doing : console.log(this.state.vars), i have Object {} @ChrisG

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's `...this.state.vars`: https://jsfiddle.net/1f2up84h/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use squared brackets to put the variables inside of an object :

```
this.setState({vars: {...this.state.vars, [keys]: [val]}});
```